# What am I getting 404 errors with my static content using Django/nginx?

Tags: django, nginx

None of my media or static content shows up and I see 404 errors for all of them everytime I load a page.

snippet from my nginx/sites-enabled (these locations below are ideally where I want my static and media content to be)

```
location /media {
alias /home/django/django/proj/proj/media;
}

location /static {
alias /home/django/django/proj/proj/static;
}
```

snippet of everything 'static' related in my settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "media")

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static")

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static"),
]

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
```

Comment: did you do `python manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: yes, it didnt resolve the issue, i'm also not sure it was even necessary to do that because all my static files are in the directories specified above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nginx aliases have to match your `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` settings, or nginx won't know where to find these files.

```
location /media {
    alias /home/django/django/proj/proj/site_media/media;
}

location /static {
    alias /home/django/django/proj/proj/site_media/static;
}
```

If that doesn't work, check where nginx tries to find the file in your error logs.

Serving media files is quite simple: you only need to tell nginx that requests made to `MEDIA_URL + '<filename>'` should serve a file named `MEDIA_ROOT + '<filename>'`. Those are your `location` and `alias` settings in nginx.

Static files are a bit more complicated. The way Django works with static files, is that `manage.py collectstatic` uses your `STATICFILES_FINDERS` to find all static files. This includes all files in your `STATICFILES_DIRS` directories. A [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) is made in your `STATIC_ROOT` directory with the same relative name.

As you can't create a symbolic link with the exact same full path+name as the file is links to, your `STATIC_ROOT` needs to be different from your `STATICFILES_DIRS`. If all your static files reside in your app-specific static folders, you can omit the `STATICFILES_DIRS`. The `STATIC_ROOT` setting is required, though, as Django *needs* a folder for all the symbolic links in order to collect the files.

These symbolic links are a way to allow third-party apps (that are not in your project root) to still provide static files. Even though your static files can be all over the place, e.g. in your folder with python packages, you only ever need to configure nginx for one specific location of static files. This greatly simplifies your server configuration.

Those symbolic links are also why you *always* need to run `collectstatic` after you've made a change in your static files. Otherwise, nginx won't find a link that tells where the actual file is located, and can't serve that file.

Comment: Okay thank you, but how do I just get rid of the site_media folder?  I don't want that,  Ideally I would like to use the paths specified in the nginx sites-enabled file

Comment: Do I remove 'site_media' from MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "media")

Comment: @Dr.Donnaloia Yes, exactly that. You need to specify a different directory in your `STATICFILES_DIRS` settings though, and copy all the files there, as they don't play nice if they are the same as `STATIC_ROOT` iirc.

Comment: @Dr.Donnaloia Basically, `STATIC_URL` matches your `location`, and `STATIC_ROOT` matches your `alias`. The same for media. `STATICFILES_DIRS` is where your static files live, and `STATIC_ROOT` is where Django creates links to all the files found by your staticfiles loaders.

Comment: I changed the OP above to reflect the changes you told me but I got an error saying static root cannot be the same as staticfiles_dirs, like you said.  However, I don't know what I should change static root to.

Comment: I don't really understand, I just want it to work at this point.  What should I change static root to?  Can I just delete that line?

Answer (score 0):

Change the paths in the nginx configuration (note the `site_media` part)?

```
location /media {
    alias /home/django/django/proj/proj/site_media/media;
}

location /static {
    alias /home/django/django/proj/proj/site_media/static;
}
```

And change the `MEDIA_URL` settings to point to valid url:

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

Comment: I want my paths to be, /home/django/django/proj/proj/site_media/media
/home/django/django/proj/proj/site_media/static,  but I don't know how to accomplish this.